# Binding.scala vs Haoyi's Scala.Rx + ScalaTags

Tags: scala.js, scalatags, binding.scala, scala.rx

How does Binding.scala compare to the concept described [here](http://www.lihaoyi.com/hands-on-scala-js/#FRPwithScala.Rx)?

Apart from the design descriptions one might compare their implementations of TodoMVC:

- [Binding.scala](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/todo/blob/master/js/src/main/scala/com/thoughtworks/todo/Main.scala)
- [Scala.Rx + ScalaTags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/blob/todomvc/src/main/scala/example/ScalaJSExample.scala)

Edit: By now I compared them to [scalajs-react](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react). I think react has a better performance, since e.g. for lists it updates only changed elements of the lists in the DOM, not the whole list.

Comment: Here is the comparison by the author of Binding.scala (if you haven't already seen): https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala#comparison-to-other-reactive-web-frameworks